Getting error while calling the sharepoint API for List Data - List Items Data without any select query
0
I'm getting this error while calling the API for getting list Data using PostMan
https://hostname.sharepoint.com/sites/random_site/_api/web/lists(guid'be7ca91-2715-4b86-8299-7925f99b7536')/items
for above request below is the response
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "-2147467259, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Cannot complete this action.\n\nPlease try again."
        }
    }
}

But when I change the url by adding a select query and select all the possible fields like below I am getting a 200 Response, how do i fix this ?:
https://hostname.sharepoint.com/sites/random_site/_api/web/lists(guid'be7ca91-2715-4b86-8299-7925f99b7536')/items$select=FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject,RoleAssignments,AttachmentFiles,ContentType,GetDlpPolicyTip,FieldValuesAsHtml,FieldValuesAsText,FieldValuesForEdit,File,Folder,LikedByInformation,ParentList,Properties,Versions,FileSystemObjectType,Id,ServerRedirectedEmbedUri,ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl,ContentTypeId,Title,ComplianceAssetId,OData__ColorTag,ID,Modified,Created,AuthorId,EditorId,OData__UIVersionString,Attachments,GUID,FileRef,FileDirRef,FileLeafRef,UniqueId,EncodedAbsUrl
Expecting a 200 Response on this api: https://hostname.sharepoint.com/sites/random_site/_api/web/lists(guid'be7ca91-2715-4b86-8299-7925f99b7536')/items
